# Azure Durable Function Error Deployin in Azure subscription

Tags: c#, azure, function, dependency-injection

[image: Error in AZ Durable Function]

I get this error in my AZ Durable.

Operating System: Linux.

Csproj file content:

TargetFramework=>netcoreapp3.1

AzureFunctionsVersion=>v3

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.5" 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.2.2" />
```

Startup.cs code: (..)

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)          
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

  builder.Services.RegisterServices(configuration);     
  builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
}
```

RegisterServices()...

public static void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services, Configuration configuration)
{

```
        ConfigApi configApi = configuration.GetSection(ConfigApi.Section).Get<ConfigApi>();

        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ConfigApi), configApi);

        ApiManagerMap apiManager = configuration.GetSection(ApiManagerMap.Section).Get<ApiManagerMap>();
        var endpointList = apiManager.ApiList.ToList();

        services.AddSingleton(new AssetServiceConfig
        {
            AssetServiceEndpoint = endpointList.First(p => p.ApiName == "AssetService")
        });
        services.AddScoped<IAssetService, AssetService>();

        services.AddScoped<ICatalogMap>(x => new CatalogMap(
            x.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(), x.GetRequiredService<IAssetService>()));

        services.AddSingleton(new PimServiceConfig
        {
            PimServiceEndpoint = endpointList.First(p => p.ApiName == "PIMService")
        });
        services.AddScoped<IPimService, PimService>();

        services.AddSingleton(new CatalogServiceConfig
        {
            CatalogServiceEndpoint = endpointList.First(p => p.ApiName == "CatalogService")
        });

        services.AddScoped<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
```

}

Function Code Constructor Code: (..)

```
private readonly ICatalogMap catalogMap;
private readonly IPimService pimService;
private readonly ICatalogService catalogService;
private readonly ConfigApi configApi;

public DownloadAndProcess(ICatalogMap catalogMap, IPimService pimService, ICatalogService catalogService, ConfigApi configApi)
{
  this.catalogMap = catalogMap;
  this.pimService = pimService;
  this.catalogService = catalogService;
  this.configApi = configApi;
}
```

When I deploy this to my AZ subscription, always get the error provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Azure Functions Core Tools to be running 3.x.
You can check by running func in the terminal.
[image]

If you are not running 3.x, please run  the below command. Check core tools version and try redeploying it.

`sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-3`

Ref : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: "The Azure Functions Core Tools provide a local development experience for creating, developing, testing, running, and debugging Azure Functions". I was used the version 3, as you can see in csproj file provided. But, tx!

Comment: @Tulio,  I understand that. You could refer the github issue in case the above doesn't solve your issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/32 . My understanding is that the core tools version is client dependent & need not be mentioned in the code.